# Full SVD of a large sparse matrix (where only the eigenvalues are required)

Tags: r, matlab, octave, svd

I am trying to run the full SVD of a large (120k x 600k) and sparse (0,1% of non-null values) matrix M. Due to memory limitation all my previous attempts failed (with SVDLIBC, Octave, and R) and I am (almost) resigned to exploring other approaches to my problem (LSA).

However, at the moment, I am only interested in the eigenvalues of the diagonal matrix S and not in the left/right singular vectors (matrices U and V).

Is there a way to compute those singular values without storing in memory the dense matrix M and/or the singular vector matrices U and V?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[EDIT] My server configuration: 3,5GHz/3,9GHz (6 cores / 12 threads) 128GB of RAM

Comment: You can check the new `rARPACK` package or `irlba` which works well with `bigmemory::big.matrix` object or sparse matrix.

Comment: I checked these packages already, however it seems they are suitable only when a few singular values are required...

Answer (score 1):

Looking for the meaning of that values (elements of matrix S from a [SVD decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition)) in wikipedia we get:

> The non-zero singular values of M (found on the diagonal entries of Σ)
>   are the square roots of the non-zero eigenvalues of both M*M and MM*

So you can look for the eigenvalues of the matrix A*A' (120k x 120k) without explicitly build the matrix, of course.

By the way, I dont think you are interested in ALL the eigenvalues (or singular values) for a matrix with such a dimensions. I do not think that any algorithm will give enough accurate results.

Comment: Thank you. The thing is that I am trying to apply the `Eigenvalue-one criterion' to find the optimal dimensionality for LSA. This approach requires all of the eigenvalues so as to compute their mean. Also, I'd rather not implement all the matrix operations by myself.

Comment: If you need the mean of the eigenvalues of a (square) matrix, this is easy. It is the same as the mean of the diagonal elements of the matrix (ivariant under change of basis) Look at here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It helped. However, it appears that the Eigenvalue-one criterion' is not suitable when working with big matrices (too many dimensions to retain); so I need to try something different. I am considering running the `Scree test', but here I would need as many eigenvalues as possible...

Comment: For anyone working on this this paper may solve this last problem (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.5870.pdf)

Comment: "So you can look for the eigenvalues of the matrix A*A' (120k x 120k) without explicitly build the matrix, of course." How 'd you do that? @sebas is it enough to have (eigen(A %*% t(A))?

Answer (score 1):

How comfortable are you with Fortran? I think you should be able to complete the computations using prebuilt packages available [here](http://www.netlib.org/svdpack/) and/or [here](http://sun.stanford.edu/~rmunk/PROPACK/). Also, if you're open to C++ and a decomposition using randomized and re-orthonormalized matrices, you can try the code at the google code project called redsvd. (I can't post the link because I don't have the requisite reputation for three links, but you can search for redsvd and find it readily.)

Comment: thanx for your help. I have no experience with Fortran but redsvd seems worth a try as it's pretty straightforward. I'll be back.